# Flash Image Stream webcam fault/bug

Tags: rfc1123

Can you tell me a simple way or link to software that I can use to block flash from uploading images from my computer in chat sites to other users???

I have disconnected and removed my built in webcam but it still streams images, possible
 because I have the HP Pavillion connected to a PLASMA Monitor which confuses me because it does not  have a camera on it!!!

I have research  possibility's of stopping this but found no answer, I will really appreciate it if you would be so kind to explain  a way to stop or block this from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Flash will usually throw a 'allow/deny' box up at you if it wants to to access any other hardware like your webcam.

So just don't 'allow' it.

You can check if you have a webcam via your device manager.

Assuming you're using Windows 7:
Press start,
Type "device manager"
Press enter and search through seeing if you can find your webcam. If there is one it should be under 'sound video and game controllers'
If you do find it. Right click on it and 'disable' it.

Good Luck.